# python ImportError "module named termios" on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm working to build a app to upload image to imgur on GAE with python27, I have downloaded some extra modules from github (pyimgur), which require some modules to be in the app directory which I have installed & placed it under LIB directory & I was able to eliminate each error one by one until till last one turned up, I'm not sure how to fix it, as I couldn't find any pip module for it. The error I am getting is

**ImportError: No module named termios**

So I do I install it? or Include it?

other module required {which I've them installed & placed it under my app directory are}

1.auth

2.decorator

3.httplib2

4.oauth2

5.pyimgur

6.requests

here's :[gae error log](http://pastebin.com/1baVmKEZ) it's on line 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a number of pyimgur libraries available.  I would make sure that you are using the correct one.

It looks like you are trying to use this library based on the other dependencies you have installed (decorator, oauth2, requests) https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur

However, there is no auth module in that library, so line 28 of your uploadimage.py file doesn't make any sense because there is no `auth` to import.

```
from pyimgur import auth
```

Try out the library I linked instead.